# How to select an input according to a parent sibling label

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

The input element that I have does not have anything to identify it because is my page is built through a react framework. So I want to select the appropriate input by its label above it. My HTML looks like the following:

```
<div>
  <label>Project</label>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
        <input>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Type</label>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
        <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to perform an action on a label which has [associated input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement/control) element Playwright will automatically retarget the action to the input.

If the DOM structure is always the same you can try something like this

```py
page.locator('div:has( > :text-matches("Project")) + div input')
```

Otherwise [layout selector](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#selecting-elements-based-on-layout) is your best bet.

Comment: Yes it works. Can you explain it please ? How did you end up with this selector?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [layout selectors](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#selecting-elements-based-on-layout):

```
const div = page.locator('input:right-of(:text("Project"))');
```